# Angular: best way to handle two+ projects (client + admin panels)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

I have two projects, both of them use separated angular cli projects (btw: i use Angular 5.2.4).

On server there are placed like this:

- /   /* here comes client angular project build */
- /admin   /* here
  comes admin angular project build */

But there is an issue: if first I go to my root client webpage - all routes are handled, as they are in client-root project, which is incorrect => so i can't get into my /admin project.

my admin project is build with `--base-href` option

---

How can i use two projects on the same domain? Root client project will handle all routes, except `/admin*`, and `/admin*` - only admin routes. Is it possible?

I thought about using this functionality: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps  - but seems it's not for my case.

Comment: are you taking about the nginx/apache configuration?

Comment: @JinsPeter nginx, and iis on other machine...

Comment: what?? why both??

Comment: @JinsPeter one for dev, another for prod :)

Comment: you are asking this question about prod ryt??. I'm sure you wont be ng-serving  together... right. as you have two different ngcli projects.. which server do u use for production

Comment: Is this what you are looking for??? @byCoder

Comment: @JinsPeter IIS for prod

Comment: @JinsPeter maybe :) I have to check it.

Comment: If you are using iis for prod, then there should be similar things.

Comment: @JinsPeter tested - until i get to root angular app - everything is fine. But when i load it - after that every route is again handled as part of client app

Comment: Means what. do u navigate from client app to admin app using a link?? If so give a complete page refresh mechanism. the two are total different apps. otherwise use, _blank to open new tav

Comment: @JinsPeter via url typing in input

Comment: url typing input?? addressbar??

Comment: @JinsPeter yep, addressbar

Answer (score 1):

I handled same use case in nginx configuration with `/api` plced first and `/` then.

So, in your apache/nginx conf file, place the

```
/admin {
    #config to direct to your admin website
}
```

and below that

```
/ {
   #config to direct to your website
}
```

Try this and comment below

Answer (score 0):

Build the admin project using the following CLI command

```
ng build --base-href=/admin/
```

This will update the base href in the index.html page to base `href="/admin/"`